# Case class without parameters alternative

Tags: scala, case-class

During some simple scala coding exercise I ran into ideological problem of *case classes without parameters* and *constructor parameters duplication*.

It all started with the following *two quite simple classes*:

```
  trait Namespace

  case class Reply[T](namespace: Namespace, correlation: String, data: Try[T])

  abstract class Request(val namespace: Namespace, val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString) {

    def success[T](data: T) = Reply(namespace, id, Try(data))

    def failure(msg: String) = Reply(namespace, id, Failure(new RuntimeException(msg)))
  }
```

Now let's assume i have an entity `Post` and I want to add `All` class as a *command to query all records* of type `Post`. In my current set up it would be easier to actually write the following:

```
case class All extends Request(Posts)
```

However in this case I get compiler warning that **case classes without parameters are deprecated**. So one might suggest to rewrite it into the following:

```
case object All extends Request(Posts)
```

However in this case object All will be instantiated only once along with its `id` field which would like to avoid **having unique id for each request**.

Could you please suggest a better way of representing `All` command so that it **would not be required to duplicate constructor arguments**?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual warning is that

> case classes without a parameter list are not allowed; use either case
>   objects or case classes with an explicit `()' as a parameter list.

So give this class an empty parameter list, just as suggested by the compiler:

```
case class All() extends Requests(Posts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `case class` or `case object`, just use a companion apply instead. You don't really want an object here anyway, if you need a unique ID for every request.

```
class All extends Requests(Posts)

object All {
  def apply(): All = new All()
}

getPosts(All())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, however, how about equality? In the case of case class I get equals (==) for free. In this case it is required from my side to code it.

Comment: Also how about serialization? In the case class I would also get it for free

Comment: @tkachuko What do you need them for? Do them manually if you need to.